# Selecting entries with the same count as in another table

Tags: mariadb, subquery, count

I'm using a SELECT statement to select multiple IDs and than use

```
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = someNumber
```

to only have the IDs with a certain count.

What I however actually want to do is to select all those IDs that have the same count that they have in another table.
I tried some variations of the following but couldn't get my desired result.

```
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(entryName_ID) FROM entryNames)
```

Is it even possible to do what I want? And if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, You can try something like this.

This will get count per ID from `table1` and `table2` and then return only those records where T1.ID count matches the second table

```
SELECT T1.ID FROM
(
    SELECT ID,Count(*) c 
    From Table1 GROUP BY ID
) T1
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT ID,Count(*) c 
     From Table2 GROUP BY ID
) T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.c = T2.c
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Somehow I didn't think of just using an INNER JOIN -.-